# Capistrano deployment with Symfony 2 and Vagrant

Tags: symfony, github, capistrano

So I have a cap file linked to my github and setup to deploy my project to my server. When I run 
`bundle exec cap prod deploy` it all works without a hitch.

I can see my code being cloned from my repo, a new release folder is created and symlinked to the current folder. However any changes I've made to my code aren't reflected.

The repo being cloned is a fork of the original repo which I created when I began working on the project. I haven't made any changes to code base except adding a single line to a twig file.

I have updated the deploy.rb so that it pulls from my forked repo instead of the original one and can see the code change in my latest commit. However the change is not reflected on the site.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Cheers

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix this will be very much appreciated, if you need any more information then please let me know and i'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities come to mind other than using the incorrect URL to the forked git repository -

1. I occasionally try to deploy a new copy of my own site, but I have **not yet pushed** the latest code from my development server (and the local repo) to the live repo on Github, but it is from Github that the code is being fetched from during deployment.
2. As a final step, Capistrano changes the location that the **'current' symlink** points to the newly deployed directory in the 'releases' directory. Your webserver (apache or Nginx must be set to use the 'current' symlink) as part of the base directory (it will probably be ..../current/web/, and then auto-load app.php from that directory, unless there a subdirectory/file exists, for .CSS/JS/images/etc). If the webserver config refers to the 'release' directory, and not the symlink, it will only be a specific, older, deployment.

Comment: The plot thickens... when I check the .conf file for the site in the site-available folder, it shows that all the symlinks are set to the current folder. Very odd behaviour as I've noticed that the same thing happens on my local copy as well. I add a change, save the file, clear cache (both browser and symfony) and refresh the page... nada, no update. Weirdest thing is if I then ssh into vagrant and check the file I edited it **has** updated. The update just isn't shown. tfw; being trolled by a virtual machine -.-

Comment: FYI, I am definitely updating the correct file, I ran a search for the string (pre change) across the whole project and it's the only appears once, in the expected twig.html file...

I have also tried, reprovisioning and reloading my vagrant VM. No dice.

Comment: DERPED it... if I add /app_dev.php changes appear. Still not working on live site but at least I can make edits locally. Any help for the live site problem would be handy, will post the answer if I find it...